# How to merge csv file with different column numbers using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want merge multiple file with different number of columns. Seem I can merge but I'm not able to write the column names.

```
indir="/home/centos/Data/MERGED/"
fileList=glob.glob(indir+"*.tsv")
dd=[pd.read_csv(f,sep="\t",header=0)for f in fileList]
result=pd.concat(dd,axis=1, join='inner', ignore_index=True,sort=False)
column_file=[]
for f in fileList:
    tp=pd.read_csv(f,sep="\t",header=0)
    print(len(tp.columns.tolist()))
    column_file.append(",".join(tp.columns.tolist()))
344
119
177
304
502
178
36
80
478
375
502
166
```

Comment: setting ignore_index to True will cause the columns to be renamed.

Comment: OK, remove `ignore_index=True`, why did you add it to your code if you didn't want to do what it is specifically meant to do?